# How do I fix 'KeyError: 'series' in BLS API sample Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I'm trying to replicate the "API Version 2.0 Python Sample Code" provided by the Bureau of Labor Statistics (BLS) on [its website here](https://www.bls.gov/developers/api_python.htm#python1), but receive "KeyError: 'series'" whenever I try to run it.

```
import requests
import json
import prettytable
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps({"seriesid": ['CUUR0000SA0','SUUR0000SA0'],"startyear":"2011", "endyear":"2014"})
p = requests.post('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/', data=data, headers=headers)
json_data = json.loads(p.text)
for series in json_data['Results']['series']:
    x=prettytable.PrettyTable(["series id","year","period","value","footnotes"])
    seriesId = series['seriesID']
    for item in series['data']:
        year = item['year']
        period = item['period']
        value = item['value']
        footnotes=""
        for footnote in item['footnotes']:
            if footnote:
                footnotes = footnotes + footnote['text'] + ','
        if 'M01' <= period <= 'M12':
            x.add_row([seriesId,year,period,value,footnotes[0:-1]])
    output = open(seriesId + '.txt','w')
    output.write (x.get_string())
    output.close()
```

Here is the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-b89f58b9b664> in <module>
      3 p = requests.post('https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/', data=data, headers=headers)
      4 json_data = json.loads(p.text)
----> 5 for series in json_data['Results']['series']:
      6     x=prettytable.PrettyTable(["series id","year","period","value","footnotes"])
      7     seriesId = series['seriesID']

KeyError: 'series'
```

I don't understand the cause of this error. Will you please help me figure it out and fix it? Many thanks!

Comment: Your code works fine for me: https://replit.com/@JohnnyMopp/CarpalWrithingSquare#main.py

Comment: Thanks for trying. Alas, I don't understand why it isn't working for me. :(

Comment: What is the content of `json_data['Results']` for you? It is quite possible api.bls.gov is only returning partial results, or perhaps malformed results on your end.

Comment: I just ran the exact same code as yesterday and it seems to work fine today... I'm not sure what the difference is. Hopefully it's fixed... Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

the code works for me,
this is the output :

```
+-------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
|  series id  | year | period |  value  | footnotes |
+-------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M12   | 134.207 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M11   | 135.107 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M10   | 135.891 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M09   | 136.211 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M08   | 136.127 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M07   | 136.392 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M06   | 136.433 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M05   | 136.216 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M04   | 135.771 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M03   | 135.375 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M02   | 134.542 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2014 |  M01   | 134.017 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M12   | 133.509 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M11   | 133.596 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M10   | 133.876 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M09   | 134.255 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M08   | 134.098 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M07   | 133.919 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M06   | 133.900 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M05   | 133.626 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M04   | 133.421 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M03   | 133.558 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M02   | 133.204 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2013 |  M01   | 132.137 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M12   | 131.770 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M11   | 132.208 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M10   | 132.892 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M09   | 132.988 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M08   | 132.430 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M07   | 131.731 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M06   | 131.956 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M05   | 132.154 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M04   | 132.284 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M03   | 131.905 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M02   | 130.953 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2012 |  M01   | 130.438 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M12   | 129.844 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M11   | 130.196 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M10   | 130.373 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M09   | 130.635 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M08   | 130.351 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M07   | 129.983 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M06   | 129.846 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M05   | 129.999 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M04   | 129.483 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M03   | 128.585 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M02   | 127.363 |           |
| SUUR0000SA0 | 2011 |  M01   | 126.778 |           |
+-------------+------+--------+---------+-----------+
```

can you try to run the code inside your terminal insead of using ipython ?